# Stand the Patriot act in the U.S.A. a the Enabling act in Nazi Germany on equal footing?

Tags: united-states, germany, history

We all know that after 9/11 the [Patriot Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patriot_Act) (and new law) was constructed to give the U.S.A. more power in combating Islamic terrorists (the war on terror).

After the fire in the Reichstag in Nazi Germany, the [Enabling act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enabling_Act_of_1933) (a new law) ensued which was meant to give Hitler absolute power (thereby abolishing the Reichstag) to fight (arrest, torture, kill) the communists who were seen as terrorists.

In the U.S.A. too, people could be arrested more easily (Bush didn't take absolute power though), tortured (Guantanamo Bay), and killed in faraway lands (think of Afghanistan).

I know a question comparing the U.S.A. and Nazi Germany lies very sensitive but I really can't see any difference in changing the law and using the change for political reasons.

Many people though believe the Nazis put the building themselves on fire, as many people nowadays believe that the 9/11 terrorist attack was a U.S.A. government conspiracy. The F.B.I. knew already four days before the attack what was going to happen. And what to think about W.T.C. number seven? Etc.

Can we say these two acts stand on equal footing?

Comment: No, the [Enabling Act of 1933](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erm%C3%A4chtigungsgesetz#Erm%C3%A4chtigungsgesetz_vom_24._M%C3%A4rz_1933) main intention was to grant the government (executive branch) general legislative powers otherwised reserved to parliament (Reichstag), whereas the **Patriot Act** did not. The **Patriot Act** does **not** grant the the executive branch legislative powers to enact laws, thus bypassing Congress as the *Enabling Act of 1933* did.

Comment: @MarkJohnson So the difference is that the enabling act gave Hitler absolute power, while the patriot act took freedom from the people?

Comment: No, Congress (legislative branch and representatives of the peaple) granted the executive branch authority to deal with a specific problem within a specific scope, whereas the Reichstag granted the executive branch legislative powers without restrictions. It like comparing a **cherry** with a **cherry tree**.

Comment: @MarkJohnson  **It like comparing a cherry with a cherry tree.** That's a good one! So the patriot (nationalistic?) act is a subset of the enabling act?

Comment: No, the **Patriot Act** was a (over)reaction of a open society that had become vulnerable because of that openness. The *Enabling Act of 1933* was the result of a planed development of the previous 10 years to abolish the existing system.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Was burning of the Reichstag included in these plans? Germany openly apologized (in 1992?) for the death of van der Lubbe (he was sentenced to death, which you know for sure).

Comment: Yes, just as the declaration of the 1st of May 1933 as the 'National Labor Holiday' in [April 1933](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_der_nationalen_Arbeit#April_1933) as a paid  national holiday was planed to bring out the last political/trade union activists (that were still free) to the streets where the SA/SS were waiting for them. The advantage of having a well thought out concept.

Comment: @MarkJohnson So it **was** a conspiracy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No

The Enabling Act was a law by which the Reichstag effectively abolished itself - **adding** legislative power to the government (Article 1, sentence 1). Government laws would be prepared by the Chancellor (Adolf Hitler) and published in the Reichsgesetzblatt (Artical 3, sentence 1). The law expires on the 1st of April 1937 **or** after the forming of a new government (Artical 5, sentence 2).
Given the suppression and intimidation of members of that body it is likely that the law itself was unconstitutional. With this legal facade, the Nazis proceeded to institute a militaristic, undemocratic and illegal regime.

The Patriot Act did not amend the constitution and is subject to all the constitutional constraints on legislative and executive power. It delegated powers to the President that were within the constitutional power of the congress to so delegate. In particular, it did not in any way transfer legislative power to the executive; that would be unconstitutional. Further, it did not purport to put the powers of either branch beyond judicial review.

Comment: But in both cases, the acts were meant to give more possibilities to those in power to combat a supposed opponent [communists, extremists, Islamic extremist, who are (were) both supposed to be a threat to society].

Comment: @descheleschilder “why” is a political question, not a legal one

Comment: Where do I ask "Why?".

Comment: What an Act was “meant” to do is a political question - what it “does” is a legal one

Comment: In both cases, one can speak of a change in the law to the advantage of those in power (Bush's administration, Hitler and his criminal friends). And in both cases, the citizens are told that it's for their own good ("Wir wollen euch schutzen von dieses Gefahr"", "We want to protect you from these dangers".)

Comment: @descheleschilder Yep, politics.

Comment: So both the U.S.A. and Nazi Germany conducted the same kind of politics?

Comment: 'The Enabling Act was **law** by which the Reichstag effectively abolished itself - **adding** legislative power to the government (Article 1, sentence 1). Government laws would be prepared by the Chancellor (Adolf Hitler) and published in the Reichsgesetzblatt (Artical 3, sentence 1). The law expires on the 1st of April 1937 **or** after the forming of a new government (Artical 5, sentence 2).' would be a more factual description...

Comment: ... than 'The Enabling Act was an *amendment to the constitution* by which the Reichstag effectively abolished itself - *transferring all* legislative power to the Chancellor (Adolf Hitler).'

Comment: @MarkJohnson there’s an edit button right there for you to change the answer.

Comment: One normally does not edit someone's else's answer when it changes the context. Changes made.

Comment: @MarkJohnson **'The Enabling Act was law by which the Reichstag effectively abolished itself **  What do you mean? That the democratic system seized to exist? Indeed, after the first of April, the act was no longer needed because Herr Hitler could anything he wanted anyway. Wasn't it?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder This is a law forum and deals with the laws as written. What the intention behind it was is **politics** and what came out of it is **history**. The *Enabling Act of 1933* was extended twice (to 1st of April 1941, 10th of May 1943) and became moot on the 26th of April 1942 when Hitler was granted absolute power. The **political goal** was to abolish the democratic system founded by the Weimar constitution of 1919.